# Error deploy Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Estoy intentando hacer un deploy con capistrano 3.10, en ruby.  Pero estoy recibiendo el mismo error todo el tiempo.

```
undefined local variable or method `strategy' for #<SSHKit::Backend::Netssh:0x00007f9b88026220> (SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError)
```

No tengo ningún método ni ninguna variable que se llame `strategy`

No entiendo cual puede ser el error.

¿Alguna idea?
Gracias

Comment: Por favor empieza por traducir tu pregunta pues estás en SO en español, de otro modo puede terminar cerrada

Comment: Hola iki, bienvenido a S.O. en español. ¿podrías agregar a tu pregunta el backtrace completo del error y no solo la linea específica del error? Igual cualquier otra parte del código que pienses que puede estar involucrada en el error, agrégala. Saludos

Comment: Solo me da esa línea de error...

Comment: Lo mismo ayuda: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/1950